# How to modify ggplot2 legend keys?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

Is there a way to change the width and height of the keys in the legend with ggplot2? In the following example, I would like to replace the dots in the legend with rectangles that I could adjust the width and height. I have tried to use `keywidth` without success.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "top",
    legend.title = element_blank()
  ) +
  guides(
    color = guide_legend(
      label.position = "top",
      override.aes = list(shape = 15, size = 5),
      keywidth = unit(2, "cm") # This is not giving me what I was expecting.
    )
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: instead points in chart squares, you want?

Comment: I would like to use points in the graph (this is ok already), but use rectangles in the legend. At the moment, the closest I can get is to use square (shape = 15).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While @Ian's answer works, there's a far simpler way, which is to define the legend key glyph you want to use right in the `geom_point()` call.  The important point to note is that if we specify the key glyph should be a rect, we need to provide the fill aesthetic (or you'll just have empty rectangles for the glyphs):

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
  geom_point(aes(fill=Species), key_glyph='rect') +
  theme(
    legend.position = "top",
    legend.title = element_blank()
  )
```

[image]

You should be able to adjust the key dimensions from there via `guides()` or `theme()` changes to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Using inspiration from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35530580/13095326) from baptiste, one approach might be to replace the `GeomPoint$draw_key` function with `GeomBar$draw_key`.

```
GeomPoint$draw_key <- GeomBar$draw_key
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "top",
    legend.title = element_blank()
  ) +
  guides(
    color = guide_legend(
      label.position = "top",
      keywidth = unit(2, "cm")
    )
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For reference, I am posting the solution.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species, fill = Species)) +
  geom_point(key_glyph = "rect") +
  theme(
    legend.position = "top",
    legend.title = element_blank()
  ) +
  guides(
    color = guide_legend(
      label.position = "top",
      keywidth = unit(2, "cm"), # This is not giving me what I was expecting.
    )
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>