# How do I change the shape of the legend key glyph to a hexagon in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have been battling for a long time now to find a way to change the legend key of a ggplot2 with a hexagon. Any help or guidance are highly appreciated!

```r
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)
ggplot(iris) +
  geom_jitter(aes(x=Species,y=Sepal.Length,color=Species),width=0.25) +
  guides(color= guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 21)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-11-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Just for avoidance of doubt, do you want the legend key to be a different shape to that used in the plot?

Comment: Yes, and I want an hexagon shape

Comment: I will reframe also my question to make it more straight forward. Thank you Peter

Comment: somewhat related https://stackoverflow.com/q/63054241/7941188

Comment: Another option could be to use images instead, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/q/61327081/7941188

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create keys using `grid` commands and then pass to a `geom_` using the `key_glyph` argument.

A quick example:

```
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)

draw_key_hex <- function (data, params, size) {
    # hexagon vertex coordinates 
    v <- list(x = c(0.95, 0.725, 0.275, 0.05, 0.275, 0.725), 
              y = c(0.5, 0.110288568297003, 0.110288568297003, 0.5, 0.889711431702997, 0.889711431702997))
    # hexagon grob
    polygonGrob(v$x, v$y, 
                gp = gpar(col = data$colour,
                          fill = alpha(data$fill, data$alpha)))
}

set.seed(123)
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Species,y=Sepal.Length,color=Species)) +
  geom_jitter(width=0.25, key_glyph=draw_key_hex)
```

[image]

```
# or with fill
set.seed(123)
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Species,y=Sepal.Length,color=Species, fill=Species)) +
  geom_jitter(width=0.25, key_glyph=draw_key_hex)
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer. You should add a picture of the output. It might be worth pointing out that if the hexagons look a bit small you can still increase their size by adding the line `guides(color= guide_legend(override.aes = list( size = 20)))`